# How to move the decimal point in the stem and leaf plot of R

Tags: r, plot

'''
df = BushApproval

x = df$Approval

x

[1] 53 53 58 52 52 53 52 50 58 57 59 59 60 65 66 64 65 65 71 66 60 55 57 59 63 65 65 68 60 66
 [31] 65 66 69 69 70 73 74 77 72 76 79 80 77 81 81 83 86 86 88 84 84 80 81 55 59 56 59 59 63 57
 [61] 56 61 55 46 49 53 59 60 63 56 55 50 51 54 53 56 55 50 52 59 60 58 59 62 61 63 62 64 66 69
 [91] 70 71 69 70 71 69 71 58 57 57 58 61 59 61 60 58 61 58 63 61 63 63 64 65 66 68 63 67 62 67
[121] 68 66 70 66 66 65 68 71 69 69 73 76 73 74 74 70 77 76 76 77 77 75 76 79 80 77 81 82 82 84
[151] 83 84 86 86 87 87 87 88 89 87 90 86 51 55 57 57 55 56 57 52 55 55 56 56 53 62 59 53 58 63
[181] 62 57 57 48 49 50 54 54 51 52 51 51 52 51 52 53 57 55 61 65 71 68 53 61 55 56 60 61 61 65
[211] 70 61 65 68 70 73 71 74 83 81 82 85 85 85 85 85 88 88 84 86 86 82 50 57 57 55 56 52 54 54
[241] 54 52 52 55 63 62 54 62 53 55 64 61 65 70 70 72 75 75 77 82 87 89 84 78 55 52 55 52 56 54
[271] 64 59 60 63 59 57 55 58 49 53 49 48 49 50 45 52 53 58 61 57 54 54 57 62 57 63 64 63 63 62
[301] 69 69 70 69 74 74 74 77 79 78 80 81 82 81 78 82 50 47 51 52 52 53 57

stem(x)

The decimal point is at the |

44 | 0

46 | 00

48 | 0000000

50 | 00000000000000

52 | 00000000000000000000000000000

54 | 000000000000000000000000000

56 | 0000000000000000000000000000

58 | 00000000000000000000000

60 | 000000000000000000000

62 | 00000000000000000000000

64 | 000000000000000000

66 | 00000000000

68 | 0000000000000000

70 | 00000000000000000

72 | 000000

74 | 0000000000

76 | 0000000000000

78 | 000000

80 | 00000000000

82 | 0000000000

84 | 00000000000

86 | 000000000000

88 | 000000

90 | 0
'''

The out is wrong. how do i move the decimal point? to get something like

x = c(91,92,93)

stem(x)

9|1,2,3

Answer (score 0):

just add stem(x, scale = 0.5). I am so stupid.